# data-atom cson configuration for Windows authentication remote

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, atom-editor

I can't connect to an mssql server using Windows Authentication on data-atom. I've successfully connected to servers using SQL server authentication, so I know data-atom is working. However, I can't figure out the proper parameters for windows authentication.

I normally log in using `runas.exe /netonly /user:REALDOMAIN\YOURDOMAINUSERNAME Ssms.exe` and then do windows authentication from there.

I've launched atom both using the `netonly runas` commands and normally. However, I am not able to find the proper parameters to connect to the server.

I've tried doing

```
{
name: WindowsAuth
protocol: "mssql"
user: = Username
password: ""
server: <ServerName>
database: "Master"
options: "domain=remoteDomain"
}
```

and

```
{
name: WindowsAuth
protocol: "mssql"
user: = remoteDomain\Username
password: ""
server: <ServerName>
database: "Master"
options: "domain=remoteDomain"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to know is that many data-atom connection questions can be resolved by looking at the documentation for tedious.js

In this specific case, even though you are using windows authentication, you need to give your username and password. Furthermore, the domain information is case sensitive, and needs to be stripped of anything like .local or .com.

Finally, you should not include any options related to trustedConnection. The domain option is sufficient.

My final configuration looks like

```
{
name: WindowsAuth
protocol: "mssql"
user: = remote_domain_username
password: password
server: server_name
database: root_db
options: "domain=remote_domain_match_case"
}
```

Though, it is best practice not to store your password in your config file. Instead, type it in whenever you open a new connection.